# Python Tkinter: Creating checkbuttons from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter, checkbox

I am building a gui in tkinter with a list `task_list = []`.

Tasks are appended to/deleted from the list in the gui.

I want a window with checkboxes for every item in the list.

So if there's 10 items in the list, there should also be 10 checkboxes.
If there's 5 items in the list, there should be 5 corresponding checkboxes.

Can this be done?

I can't find anything on it

Thanks!

Comment: this can certainly be done, just loop over the list using a `for` loop and each iteration create a Radiobutton and pack it, that would be the basic stuff at least

Comment: Yes it can be done. Just iterate over the items in a list, creating a checkbutton for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here.

```
from tkinter import *
task_list=["Call","Work","Help"]
root=Tk()
Label(root,text="My Tasks").place(x=5,y=0)
placement=20
for tasks in task_list:
    Checkbutton(root,text=str(tasks)).place(x=5,y=placement)
    placement+=20
root.mainloop()
```

Using grid.

```
from tkinter import *
task_list=["Call","Work","Help"]
root=Tk()
Label(root,text="My Tasks").grid(row=0,column=0)
placement=3
for tasks in task_list:
    Checkbutton(root,text=str(tasks)).grid(row=placement,column=0,sticky="w")
    placement+=3
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: dude, there is `pack()` option, why wouldn't You use that in this case, it would save some space to avoid writing `placement` and incementing it? also no need to use `str(tasks)` because `tasks` is already a string

Comment: @Sujay Thank you - I have used .grid in my entire GUI, is there any way to make use of what you just showed me but with grid placement? I tried it and it only shows 1 check button (the newest task) in the grid I specify, which makes sense I guess.

Comment: @KarimLoberg for grid it would be possible to `for index, item in enumerate(task_list):` and then `Checkbutton(master, **options).grid(column=0, row=index)` and btw it is possible to mix up layout managers in different containers so for example if one frame uses `grid()` a different frame could use `pack()` if need be

Comment: `**options` part confuses me and the `item` part is just what was previously named `tasks`, right?

Comment: I figured it out. Small detail; if i want the boxes to be unchecked everytime i acces the window they're located in, is there any way of doing that in a simple way?
I just noticed now that the boxes are still checked the next time i open the window they're in

Comment: Also how do i "grab" items checked in boxes so I can do something with them?

Comment: Why have You put that `placement` like that? that is completely pointless and makes no sense. First of rows start from 0 but in this case the checkbutton rows would start from 1 because label is on the row 0. But there is no need to increment that by 3. That achieves nothing. just start with `placement = 1` and increment like this: `placement += 1` adding extra rows is pointless (as I have mentioned a couple times already) if You want to have spacing between use `padx` and `pady` arguments of the `grid()` method. Also as I stated in my comment might as well use `enumerate` to get the row

Comment: @KarimLoberg the `**option` and `master` part can be ignored, basically instead of that You would write what the OP wrote there and yes `item` is the same as `tasks` in my given loop. To get the selected value You would need to use a `StringVar` and assign it to the `value` attribute of Checkbutton, tho note that for each Checkbutton there has to be a separate `StringVar`. Then You can just use `.get()` method of `StringVar`. (I will just write an answer in a while and explain this)

Comment: @Matiiss sounds good. But how can I make a separate `StringVar` for each Checkbutton when the number of checkbuttons depends on the amount of items in the `task_list[]`.
The number of checkbuttons will thus be varying

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for this issue:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, IntVar, Frame, Label
from functools import partial

task_list = ['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Work', 'Study']


def choose(index, task):
    print(f'Selected task: {task}' if var_list[index].get() == 1 else f'Unselected task: {task}')


root = Tk()

Label(root, text='Tasks').grid(column=0, row=0)

frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=0, row=1)

var_list = []

for index, task in enumerate(task_list):
    var_list.append(IntVar(value=0))
    Checkbutton(frame, variable=var_list[index],
                text=task, command=partial(choose, index, task)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

First I would like to mention that it is possible to mix layout manager methods like in this example. The main window uses `grid` as layout management method and I have gridded a frame to the window, but notice that `Checkbuttons` are getting packed, that is because frame is a different container so it is possible to use a different layout manager, which in this case makes it easier because pack just puts those checkbuttons one after another.

**The other stuff:**
There is the task list which would contain the tasks.

Then I have defined a **function `choose()`** this function prints out something. It depends on a variable. The comparison happens like this: print out this if value is this else print out this. It is just an `if/else` statement in one line and all it checks is if the `IntVar` in that list in that specific index is value 1 so "on". And there are two argument this function takes in: `index` and `task`. The index is meant to get the according `IntVar` from the `var_list` and the `task` is meant to display what tasks was chosen or unchosen.

Then the simple `root = Tk()` and `root.mainloop()` at the end.

Then is the label that just explains it.

Then the frame and here You can see that both label and frame were gridded using `.grid()`

Then the `var_list = []` just creates an empty list.

**Then comes the loop:**
It loops over each item in the `task_list` and extracts the index of that item in the list and the value itself. This is done by using `enumerate()` function.

Each iteration appends a `IntVar(value=0)` to the `var_list` and since this appending happens at the same time as the items are read from the `task_list` the index of that `IntVar` in the list is the same as the current item in the `task_list` so that same index can be used for access.

**Then a `Checkbutton` is created**, its master is the `frame` (so that `.pack()` can be used) and the `text=task` so it corresponds to task name, the variable is set as a specific item in the `var_list` by index and this all has to be done so that a reference to that `IntVar` is kept. Then comes `command=partial(choose, index, task)` which may seem confusing but all `partial` does is basically this function will now execute always with the variables just given so those variables will always be the same for this function for this Checkbutton. And the first argument of `partial` is the function to be executed and next are arguments this function takes in. Then the `Checkbutton` gets packed.

If You have any questions ask.

**Useful sources:**

- [About `partial()` (though there are other sources too)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/partial-functions-in-python)
- [About `Checkbutton` (other sources about this too)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm)
- [One line `if/else` statements](https://www.pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/)